# Powershell loop iteration

Tags: powershell

```
#gets the file location/file name of the IP address
Param($addr)
$file = Get-Content $addr
$i = 0
while ($i -ne $file.Count) {
  Write-Host $file
  $i++
}
```

Output:

```
8.8.8.8 127.0.0.1 208.67.222.222
8.8.8.8 127.0.0.1 208.67.222.222
8.8.8.8 127.0.0.1 208.67.222.222
```

File content:

```
8.8.8.8
127.0.0.1
208.67.222.222
```

I only want it to iterate and print out one line, not all three lines on a single line 3 times. I need this so I can run a ping command on each address.

Comment: If you only want one line then you should be indexing, which you are not currently, in your line `write-host $file`. So the simple _fix_ would be to `$file[$i]`. But you could be using different loop structures alltogether. `get-content $addr | Foreach-Object{ "do something with $_"}`

Comment: This worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use the index operator `[]` on `$file`.

```
#gets the file location/file name of the IP address
param($addr)
$file = get-content $addr
$i=0 
while ($i -ne $file.count){
   write-host $file[i]
   $i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $_ as file row with pipe like this :

```
Param($addr)
Get-Content $addr | foreach{ $_ }


#short version
Param($addr)
gc $addr | %{ $_ }
```